# Selective mirroring over FTP

Tags: ftp, mirroring

I need to keep my web page synchronized with a local directory.
A very effective tool is `lftp`, which I use with the script:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   HOST='ftp.remote.it'
   USER='username'
   PASS='password'
   TARGETFOLDER='.'
   BASEFOLDER='/home/my/folder/'
   SOURCEFOLDER='_site'

   cd $BASEFOLDER || exit
   lftp -f "
   open $HOST
   user $USER $PASS
   mirror --reverse --only-newer --ignore-time --delete \
          --verbose $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
   bye
   "
```

By using the option `--delete` I make sure that when I delete a file locally, the corresponding file is deleted remotely too. However, on the website I put additionaly stuff which does not come from the local website and which I do not want to delete when I make an update (the effect of `--delete` is that *everything* on the remote folder and subfolders not existing in the local folder is deleted).

A solution could be keeping a list of the files existing in the local folder at the last update; then, by comparing the local directory with the list, I can obtain a list of deleted files. In this way, the mirroring of the local website comes in two steps: first I delete the files on the website corresponding to the locally deleted files, then I upload all updated and new files using `lftp` **without** the option `--delete`.

However, to my surprise, I have found no way to make lftp (or any other ftp client) delete a list of files remotely taking the list from a file.

Comment: rsync can do this if you can use it (e.g. you can connect via SSH, not with FTP, which you should not use anyway).

Comment: `rsync` cannot work over FTP. I know FTP is considered unsafe, but this is what I have

Answer (score 3):

The following is untested and comes from reading the [doc](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) and adapting it to what `rsync` does.

According to the man page, `mirror` has the following options:

```
        -i RX,   --include=RX               include matching files
        -x RX,   --exclude=RX               exclude matching files
        -I GP,   --include-glob=GP          include matching files
        -X GP,   --exclude-glob=GP          exclude matching files
                 --include-rx-from=FILE
                 --exclude-rx-from=FILE
                 --include-glob-from=FILE
                 --exclude-glob-from=FILE   load include/exclude patterns from the file, one per
                                            line
```

Use them. You can keep a list of files, folders or globs (wildcards) you don't want deleted remotely on your local machine and just tell `lftp` to ignore everything that's in there, which implicitly will not delete it on the remote side (unless you use the `--delete-excluded` switch ...). The stuff should not need to be present locally (if it behaves like `rsync` in that regard).

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on the syntax for keeping a remote folder when mirroring to a remote? `--exlude-glob` seems to exclude the subfolders from being uploaded but always removes the subfolders on the remote. Is that expected?